# Fast checksum hashing?

Tags: c#, optimization

Writing a simple program that will find exact duplicate files on my computer, but it's a bit slow. Is there any way I can speed this up?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace DupeFinder
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Getting files...");
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\Photos", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            var alg = new HMACMD5();
            var dict = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>();
            Console.WriteLine("Computing hashes...");
            int i=0;
            int cursorLeft = Console.CursorLeft;
            int cursorTop = Console.CursorTop;
            foreach(var fileName in files)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(cursorLeft,cursorTop);
                Console.Write("Hashing file {0}/{1}", ++i, files.Length);
                using(var stream = new BufferedStream(File.OpenRead(fileName),1024*1024*5))
                {
                    var hash = alg.ComputeHash(stream);
                    var str = BitConverter.ToString(hash);
                    if (!dict.ContainsKey(str)) dict[str] = new List<string>();
                    dict[str].Add(fileName);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            foreach(var dupe in dict.Where(p => p.Value.Count >= 2))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", dupe.Value));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done!");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Possible optimizations:

1. Avoid converting byte array to string first. I tried this, but it doesn't work, I guess because it's using reference equals rather than comparing the bytes.
2. Faster hashing algorithm?
3. Different stream, or buffer size? I tried doing 1024^3 which should be a megabyte, but that seemed to slow it down if anything.

Or is this just an inherently slow thing to do?

---

I remembered that that Dictionaries can accept an `IEqualityComparer`, so I can write my own `byte[]` comparer.

A lot of the algorithms I found on the internet tend to compare the byte length first, which I don't need to do, because I know it's always going to be 16 bytes. They also tend to compare 1 byte at a time... but I'm on a 64-bit machine, so why not do 8?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace DupeFinder
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Getting files...");
            string dir = @"D:\Photos";
            var files = Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            var alg = new HMACMD5();
            var dict = new Dictionary<byte[], List<string>>(new Md5Comparer());
            Console.WriteLine("Computing hashes...");
            int i = 0;
            int cursorLeft = Console.CursorLeft;
            int cursorTop = Console.CursorTop;
            foreach (var fileName in files)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(cursorLeft, cursorTop);
                Console.Write("Hashing file {0}/{1}", ++i, files.Length);
                using (var stream = new BufferedStream(File.OpenRead(fileName), 1024 * 1024 * 5))
                {
                    var hash = alg.ComputeHash(stream);
                    if (!dict.ContainsKey(hash)) dict[hash] = new List<string>();
                    dict[hash].Add(fileName);
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();

            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(dir, "duplicates.txt")))
            {
                i = 0;
                foreach (var dupe in dict.Where(p => p.Value.Count >= 2))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("Duplicate {0}", ++i);
                    foreach(var fn in dupe.Value)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine("- {0}", fn);
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Done!");
            //Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class Md5Comparer : IEqualityComparer<byte[]>
    {
        public bool Equals(byte[] x, byte[] y)
        {
            var xi = BitConverter.ToInt64(x, 0);
            var yi = BitConverter.ToInt64(y, 0);
            if (xi != yi) return false;
            xi = BitConverter.ToInt64(x, 8);
            yi = BitConverter.ToInt64(y, 8);
            return xi == yi;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(byte[] obj)
        {
            return obj[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Not sure how much faster this is.... I haven't done any benchmarking, but it certainly doesn't seem any slower.

---

New code, thanks to @spender:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace DupeFinder
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            const string dir = @"D:\Photos";
            var md5Comparer = new Md5Comparer();

            var dupeGroups = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                .Select(fn => new FileInfo(fn))
                .GroupBy(fi => fi.Length)
                .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                .SelectMany(g => g
                   .GroupBy(fi => GetHash(fi.FullName), md5Comparer)
                   .Where(g2 => g2.Count() > 1));

            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(dir, "duplicates.txt")))
            {
                int i = 0;
                foreach (var dupeGroup in dupeGroups)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("Duplicate {0}", ++i);
                    foreach(FileInfo fi in dupeGroup)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine("- {0}", fi.FullName);
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("{0:0.000} seconds", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000d); // 22.068 seconds to process 10K files, 37 GB, 463 dupes
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static readonly HMACMD5 md5Hasher = new HMACMD5();
        public static byte[] GetHash(string fileName)
        {
            using(var stream = File.OpenRead(fileName))
                return md5Hasher.ComputeHash(stream);
        }
    }

    class Md5Comparer : IEqualityComparer<byte[]>
    {
        public bool Equals(byte[] x, byte[] y)
        {
            var xi = BitConverter.ToInt64(x, 0);
            var yi = BitConverter.ToInt64(y, 0);
            if (xi != yi) return false;
            xi = BitConverter.ToInt64(x, 8);
            yi = BitConverter.ToInt64(y, 8);
            return xi == yi;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(byte[] obj)
        {
            return obj[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Down to 22-70 seconds from 360+ seconds. Quite the improvement!

Comment: are you comparing lots of large files where you are constantly rebuffering, changing using (var stream = new BufferedStream(File.OpenRead(fileName), 1024 * 1024 * 5)) to (var stream = File.OpenRead(fileName)) has performed much faster on my system.

Comment: @Gary.S: Yeah... I just tried that actually. Seems to be a bit faster. I'm hashing photos mostly. Average filesize is 280 KiB apparently. No wait...that's bad math. 3.64 MiB.

Comment: how many files are you testing and how long is it taking. I have it running 9600 files in about 4 seconds. Total size is about 760 MB.

Comment: @Gary.S: 10K files, 37 GB. Takes a few minutes.

Comment: 1024^3 (if the meaning is 1024*1024*1024) is 1Gb, not 1Mb

Comment: @6502: Woops... I was thinking bytes > kilobytes > megabytes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You missed a massive opto: If sizes don't match...

Besides, matching hashes does not guarantee matching contents.

EDIT

Ok. It's not that hard to find size based dupes which you can then check to see if they are really dupes:

For instance:

```
var files = 
    Directory
        .GetFiles(
            @"C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads",
            "*", 
            SearchOption.AllDirectories);
var fileGroups=
    files
        .Select(fn => new FileInfo(fn))
        .GroupBy(fi => fi.Length)
        .Where(g => g.Count()>1);
```

You could take it further by making a hashing function for a given filename

```
int GetHash(fileName)  //fill in your definition
```

Then...

```
var fg2 =
        fileGroups
            .SelectMany(
                g => g
                    .GroupBy(fi => GetHash(fi.FullName))
                    .Where(gg=>gg.Count()>1));

foreach(var dupeGroup in fg2)
{
    //everything in this group is probably duplicate
    //although you'd need to do byte by byte to be sure
    foreach(FileInfo dupe in dupeGroup)
    {

    }
}
```

By doing this, you're going to masively reduce the amount of hashing required because you've prefiltered the candidates by size.

Comment: How am I going to compare file sizes? That works when you have 2 files and you want to compare one to the other, but not when you want to compare one file to every other file..... unless perhaps I build a 2-level dictionary, the first being file-size, and the second being the hash. Regarding your second point....the probability of the 2 files having the same hash and NOT being identical is incredibly low. That's the entire purpose of hashes.

Comment: Secondly, even if I did build a 2-level dictionary, that would tell me immediately if there is no exact match without having to go to the 2nd level in many cases, but I'd still have to compute the hash for future comparisons. It would only save me on having to compare 2 hashes in many scenarios...but with the added complexity, I'm not positive that comparing an int+string is cheaper than comparing 2 strings. Let me know if I'm wrong... I'm just trying to follow your logic.

Comment: I removed the need for converting the byte array to a string first, now I'm just comparing 2 pairs of ints, which is probably cheaper than comparing file sizes (I don't have to query the file system for that). If you still think its a massive opto, let me know what I'm overlooking here. I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: Essentially, you want to look at all the files and consider only those who size is the same. So, generate a dictionary with this property, and then hash only the ones of the same size. This will give the dramatic speedup spender is commenting on. You can also probably check some other trivial file-specific things (headers, etc) before actually doing a hash. And then, if the hash check is the same, do byte-by-byte on that file. This is the idea.

Comment: @NoonSilk and Spender: Oh....this makes a lot more sense when you group them by filesize first. I guess I wouldn't have to hash files with a group size of 1. I'll try this a bit later....this does sound a lot faster now :D Thanks guys.

Comment: @Spender: Okay, ran some benchmarking on your suggested algo. You're absolutely right, this speeds it up by about 7 fold, and it's a lot simpler. Didn't even need a dictionary. I didn't know about `GroupBy` before...that's handy!